# Subfigures in twocolumn format

Tags: subfloats, two-column, subcaption

I am writing an article in twocolumn format, not using multicols, but including the option in the documentclass itself. Now I need to insert some figures, preferably in a subplot like format, 2x2 or 2x3 perhaps, spanning a single column.

Tried multicols. To my utter dismay it doesn't seem to support twocolumn option.
Tried subfigure/subfig. Couldn't make it work.
Minipage code looks clumsy.
Can't understand how subfloat/subcaption works.

Can someone help me out please, alongwith a preamble of exactly what packages are needed to do this?

Comment: Sory, from your questions is not clear what is your problem? span figure over two columns? or just put figures (consist of subfigures) in one column? Can you provide an example as complete small document, what you try so far? Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: put the figure (consisting of subfigures) in one column

Comment: Than please show us, what you doing. In normal circumstances this should work out-of-box. Try `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{My figure}
\label{fig:myfig-1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}`